# How to prevent Perl CGI->start_html() from printing DOCTYPE header

Tags: perl, cgi

when using Perl CGI, it always print out the: <"DOCTYPE html ".... > header before printing out the rest of the html body, which messes up the proper display of the web page. I guess the cause is the DOCTYPE still references a very old version of HTML. This first line get generated regardless when I use $query->start_html(...);. So the question is, how to prevent that <!DOCTYPE...> line from being generated? When I delete that DOCTYPE line, my web page runs properly after that. Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's not the `->start_html` method that's doing it?  ([CGI::HTML::Functions](https://metacpan.org/dist/CGI/view/lib/CGI/HTML/Functions.pod#Creating-the-HTML-document-header))

Comment: @JimDavis - thx Jim, you're right. I've edited my post. I also checked out the CGI::HTML::Functions link you gave and the ->start_html() has a "-dtd" option to specify the version. But the documentation doesn't tell how to NOT display it completely ??

Comment: You can provide the correct one using `-dtd`

Comment: Hi @ikegami, I've tried both the HTML5 and HTML4 per the page: https://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html  but none of them work. But as soon as I delete the whole line <DOCTYPE...> then the page works properly. I just can't find a way for $query->start_html() NOT to show DOCTYPE at all.

Comment: The [documentation for the HTML generation functions](https://metacpan.org/dist/CGI/view/lib/CGI/HTML/Functions.pod) says "please do not use this functionality, it is considered to be legacy and essentially deprecated". You really shouldn't be using these functions. See [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) for better options.

Comment: "But as soon as I delete the whole line `<DOCTYPE...>` then the page works properly" — If the page works when you **remove** the Doctype entirely then you are depending on Quirks Mode (in which browsers attempt to emulate the bugs that were in Internet Explorer 4.x and its peers). They aren't entirely consistent with each other in this emulation mode. You should use a Doctype which triggers Full Standards mode and fix the errors in your HTML/CSS/JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers will use the `DOCTYPE` definition to decide whether or not to interpret an HTML (or XHTML) document in [Quirks mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). I assume that's what you mean by "messes up the proper display of the web page" - you're carefully creating valid HTML5 but the browser goes into Quirks mode and the page doesn't look right.

What you want is the standard HTML `DOCTYPE` definition.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Unfortunately for you, the HTML generation functions in CGI.pm are unmaintained and don't have support for HTML5. So you can't get the module to generate this `DOCTYPE`.

Honestly, your best approach is to stop using all of the HTML generation functions and switch to a template-based approach instead. But I can see how that would be a big job so, in the short term, perhaps you can just stop using `start_html()`. It shouldn't be too hard to replace the call with a heredoc that contains the text that you want.

**Update:** The comment from Quentin below got me thinking. When I said:

> you're carefully creating valid HTML5 but the browser goes into Quirks mode and the page doesn't look right

I was completely wrong. If you get the browser behaviour you want *without* a `DOCTYPE`, then you want to put the browser into Quirks mode. And that's far easier. Using the information from the Wikipedia article I linked to above, you can see that HTML 4.01 Transitional is the most recent `DOCTYPE` that will put all modern browsers into Quirks mode. So you can use that `DOCTYPE`.

```
$ perl -MCGI=:html -E'say start_html(-dtd => "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN")'
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head><title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
```

And that should get the browsers working as you want them.

But relying on Quirks mode is fragile. I recommend that you consider fixing your HTML and CSS so that they work as you want when browsers are in Standards mode.

Comment: CGI.pm 4.48 (the version I happen to have installed) outputs ```<!DOCTYPE html
 PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">``` which triggers Almost Standards Mode (which is pretty much the same as Standards mode with the major exception being some handling of the inside of tables). That's somewhat better than the Quirks mode (which the OP gets when there is no Doctype type and which they say breaks the page).

Comment: @Quentin: As does my 4.53. But I don't think that code has changed for many years. Actually, the OP says that having no `DOCTYPE` fixes their page. So I guess they want to trigger Quirks mode.

Comment: @santa100: See the update to my answer.

Comment: Quentin/Dave, I've just tried that trick with $query->start_html( -dtd => "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"... ) that u suggested and now my page works great. Thx very much for all ur help!

Comment: @santa100: If my answer has solved your problem, please accept it. But, also, please consider fixing your HTML so it doesn't rely on Quirks mode.